# How to transform a string column of a dataframe into a column of Array[String] with Apache Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, transformation

I have a DataFrame with a column 'title_from' as below.
[image].

This colume contains a sentence and I want to transform this column into a Array[String]. I have tried something like this but it does not works.

```
val newDF = df.select("title_from").map(x => x.split("\\\s+")
```

How can I achieve this? How can I transform a datafram of strings into a dataframe of Array[string]? I want evry line of newDF to be an array of words from df.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "it does not works" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: You are absolutely right about my description. I must have described as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `withColumn` function.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val newDF = df.withColumn("split_title_from", split(col("title_from"), "\\s+"))
              .select("split_title_from")
```

Comment: When I try this I get the following two errors: 

Error:(79, 75) could not find implicit value for parameter impl: breeze.linalg.split.Impl2[org.apache.spark.sql.Column,String,VR]

    val title_from_words_df = finalDF.withColumn("title_from_words", split(col("title_from"), "\\s+")).select("title_from_words")

Error:(79, 75) not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit impl: breeze.linalg.split.Impl2[org.apache.spark.sql.Column,String,VR])VR in trait UFunc.

Unspecified value parameter impl.

What I am doing wrong? 

Thank you for your asap response!

Comment: @atheodos you have a different split function being imported. Either remove that other import, or prefix sparks split function like so `functions.split`

Comment: Thank you! It fixed when I prefix the spilt function. It works fine for me!

Answer (score -2):

Can you try following to get the list of all authors

```
scala> val df = Seq((1,"a1,a2,a3"), (2,"a1,a4,a10")).toDF("id","author")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, author: string]

scala> df.show()
+---+---------+
| id|   author|
+---+---------+
|  1| a1,a2,a3|
|  2|a1,a4,a10|
+---+---------+


scala> df.select("author").show
+---------+
|   author|
+---------+
| a1,a2,a3|
|a1,a4,a10|
+---------+

scala> df.select("author").flatMap( row => { row.get(0).toString().split(",")}).show()
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|   a1|
|   a2|
|   a3|
|   a1|
|   a4|
|  a10|
+-----+
```